# Run libgdx application on Android with unlimited FPS?

Tags: android, libgdx

A simple question - in libgdx, the default highest fps you can run at is 60 (or 61, whatever). If its a desktop question, it can be solved by using Lwjgl config

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.foregroundFPS = 0;
cfg.backgroundFPS = 0;
new LwjglApplication(new Pulmusic(), cfg);
```

But theres no such method in AndroidApplicationConfiguration, the config which must be used to  initialize the game on Android platform.

Is that a way to disable this kind of limiting fps on Android platform of libgdx?

Comment: @BennX The answer to that question is desktop specific and does not apply here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Hardware/Android specific feature.

FPS are limited automatically at 60FPS because you won't feel any difference with more FPS and thus it is limited on most devices to save energy.

You can limit it further with `Thread.sleep`, but there is no way to increase the FPS. I cannot think of any reason *why* you want that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @noone say's this is automatically blocked.
But on very old devices FPS weren't blocked. My friend has got a old samsung android phone with android 2.1 and my game is working with 300-200FPS (unstable) and on new Galaxy S3 game working in 60 FPS (very stable)